# How to detect beacons in iOS Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush-ios

I'm trying to send a push message to iOS devices from the marketing cloud via MobilePush, when the device comes near a bluetooth beacon (proximity). I called `configureSDK(...)` with all params set to `true` and `startWatchingLocation()` and also have permission to use the device's location. Also I can see my messages are being downloaded to the device as intended, but they're not fired when the beacon with corresponding uuid, major and minor values comes in range.
Did I miss something?

Normal outbound push messages from marketingcloud work as intended.

Comment: did you manage to find a working solution for this? maybe via SF Support ?

Comment: Did it finally work for you? Thanks.

Comment: Whoa, sorry for the delay. Yes, apparently I missed to call `ETRegion.retrieveProximityFromET()`. It worked then.